# Importing interactjs 1.7.2 in Angular 8 not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I'm trying to import interactive.js 1.7.2 in Angular 8. I installed as follows:

```
npm install interactjs@next
```

then imported in different ways and none worked:

```
import * as interact from 'interactjs';

import interact from 'interactjs'

import from 'interactjs';

import * as interact from '@interactjs/interactjs';

declare var interact:any; (with no imports)
```

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703625/integrating-interact-js-with-an-angular-project) seems to work for others but not for me.

I get many errors when starting up Angular so it has to be a problem with the import, for example I get:

> src/app/web/visuals/svg.rectangle.ts(65,25): error TS2349: Cannot
> invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof
> import("C:/projects/myproject/node_modules/@interactjs/interactjs/index")'
> has no compatible call signatures.
>
> ../../node_modules/@interactjs/core/Interactable.d.ts(7,19): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> ../../node_modules/@interactjs/core/Interaction.d.ts(74,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.

How to fix this issue?

**UPDATE**

This problem is documented [here](https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/300) but with no solution.

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? Can you please provide more details about your setup?

Comment: @Roy TypeScript 3.7.3, I'm using VS code and also get errors while editing the Angular file, such as `This expression is not callable.` on `interact('.item').draggable({`.

Comment: None of the 3 answers worked for me angular-15.1.0 and ts-4.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this using es5 syntax

```
const interact = require('interactjs')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import interact from 'interactjs'

interact('.item').draggable({
  onmove(event) {
    console.log(event.pageX,
                event.pageY)
  }
})
```

https://interactjs.io/

As shown on the official page

Answer (score 0):

For angular 8 below code work for me.

```
import * as InteractJS from 'interactjs/dist/interact.js';

  ngOnInit() {
    InteractJS('.item').draggable({
      onmove(event) {
        console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY);
      }
    });
  }

.item {
  touch-action: none;
  user-select: none;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}
```